# Where to get MOST data?

Tags: data-analysis, artificial-satellite

Where to get MOST data (light curves), please? Does a database or a list of objects that were  exist? I mean [MOST spacecraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOST_(spacecraft)).

Comment: Would you perhaps like to explain (or provide a link) what "MOST" refers to?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant The Microvariability and Oscillations of Stars.